# add color picker on top of an appended child

Tags: html

So I have a script that will add a text box and I want to add on top of that text box a color wheel
also I'm using electron if this helps. Any help is appreciated!

```html
<input class="addcommandbtn" type="button" id="addCommand" style="width: 6.5%;" value="+ Command">
<select name="commandslist" id="commandslist" size="18%" style="height: 59%;width: 15%; display: block; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; border-radius: 6px; margin-top: 5px;"></select>
 <script>
        function createCommandField() {
            var input = document.createElement('option');
            input.style.marginTop = "1%";
            input.textContent = "command";
            input.name = 'Commands[]';
            input.style.display = 'block'
            input.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff';
            input.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
            input.style.borderRadius = '6px';
            input.style.height = "2%";
            input.style.padding = '5px 30px';
            input.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
            input.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            input.style.fontSize = "17px";
            return input;
        }
   var select = document.getElementById('commandslist');
        document.getElementById('addCommand').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            select.appendChild(createCommandField());
        });

</script>
```

Comment: you need to add a color picker to the appended child or you need to choose a color before append a child ? also u need anycolor picker like a button to get colors from it or u need to design a color picker wheel ?

Comment: i want to add to the input var an input that is type color

Comment: you can use `input.innerHTML += '<input type="color" value="#ff00ee" style="float:left;">';` before the `return input` line but it needs a JS to run the color picker as long as it's included in an options list so it's useless and cannot be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a jquery script to get the color input changed on **EDITED**: selected option double click

added a function to apply selected color on the background of the same selection and un-select it to c the effect,

goodluck,

```js
function createCommandField() {
  var input = document.createElement('option');
  input.style.marginTop = "1%";
  input.textContent = "command";
  input.name = 'Commands[]';
  input.style.display = 'block'
  input.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff';
  input.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
  input.style.borderRadius = '6px';
  input.style.height = "2%";
  input.style.padding = '5px 30px';
  input.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
  input.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  input.style.fontSize = "17px";

  return input;

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var bgclr ='';
    var parentopt = $('#pckrbg');
  $('#commandslist').change(function() {
    var crntslct = $('#commandslist').children('option:selected');
    crntslct.dblclick(function() {
        parentopt.click();
        parentopt.change(function(){
            bgclr = parentopt.val();
            $('#commandslist').prop("selectedIndex", function(){
                $(this).children('option:selected').css("background", bgclr); //set background
                $(this).children('option:selected').prop("selected", false); //deselect option;
            });
        });     
    });
  });
});

var select = document.getElementById('commandslist');
document.getElementById('addCommand').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  select.appendChild(createCommandField());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input type="color" value="#FFEE00"  id="pckrbg" name="colorz" style="position:relative; display:none; float:left; margin-right:1rem; bottom:3px;"></span>
<form class="myformclass" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size:20px;" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input class="addcommandbtn" type="button" id="addCommand" style="width: 6.5%;" value="+ Command">
  <input class="addcommandbtn" type="button" id="removeCommand" style="width: 7.2%;" value="- Command" onclick="removeCommandFunc()">
  <input class="savebtn" type="button" id="saveCommands" style="width: 4%; float: right;" value="Save" onclick="SaveToLocalStorage()">
  <!-- Retrive Button <input class="Retrive" type="button" id="Callback" value="Retrive From LocalStorage" style="float:right;margin-right:3rem;" > -->
  <select name="commandslist" id="commandslist" size="5%" style="width: 50%; display: block; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; border-radius: 6px; margin-top: 5px;"></select>
  <select name="resplist" id="resplist" size="18%" style="height: 20%;width: 59%; display: block; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; border-radius: 6px; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 20%;"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to create the color element when a button is pressed then set the position of it to another element's position and the color element should be on top of the second element

Comment: sry could u explain it more ?

Comment: u can see that it adds a text box

Comment: when it adds a text box i also want to add a colorpicker inside that text box

Comment: first of all you could delete the unnecessary comments so, and by anyway just tell me in one comment what exactly you aims to do so i could help, best of luck

Comment: so your code is exactly what i need but i found out that there is a small bug i have a function that saves the script using localstorage but when i refresh the last text box from the commandlist it will be in another location on the screen and i also want to open the color picker when i double click on that text box

Comment: @TempAcc which Textbox ? you could share more of your code and explain more what your aiming to do !!

Comment: @TempAcc code has been edited to be used with Double-click

Comment: the textbox(i mean option) that gets added when i press + command button

Comment: @TempAcc oh ok it's called select option btw, and just share the related part of your code,

Comment: or just tell me what you mean by :  **__but when i refresh the last text box from the commandlist it will be in another location on the screen__**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227286/discussion-between-burham-b-soliman-and-tempacc).

Comment: so i have a function that will save the file when i save it and then refresh the select option wont be where it supposed to be

Comment: @TempAcc snippet edited ,dun forget to mark question as answered, goodluck bud